# Echo other content after form validation and submission

Tags: php, forms, validation

How to clear page content and show other content after I validate and submit a form?

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['Confirm'])) {
    $to = "email@email.com";
        $error = 0;
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            //Validation things
            if(trim($first_name) == '')     {$error = 1; $first_namerr = 1;}
    $msg ="
    First Name:$first_name
    -------------------------
    ";
    $sub ="Contact";
    $from = "From: Support form";
    @mail($to, $sub, $msg, $from);

//How to clear actual content and echo other ?

    }
    }
    ?>

        <form name="contact" id="contact" method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

            <label for="first_name" class="inner_text"><?php if ($error != 0){ if ($first_namerr == 1) {print("<font style='color: Red;'>");} }?>First Name<?php if ($error != 0){if ($first_namerr == 1) {print("</font>");}} ?></label>
            <input id="first_name" name="first_name" size="30" type="text" value="<? echo $first_name; ?>" /><?php if ($error != 0){ if ($first_namerr == 1) {print('<img src="images/error.gif">');} }?>    

      <input type="submit" id="Confirm" name="Confirm" value="Confirm" />
        </form>
```

I'm beginner in PHP, so please be explicit if you want to give an answer!

Comment: Use if/else control structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an if/else statement to control the content being displayed - e.g:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Confirm'])) {

    // Your mail code

?>

Thank you, your message has been sent! <!-- This content is shown after form submission -->

<?php } else { ?>

    <!-- Display your email form -->

<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: I get an error on line 81, there is located this code `<?php } else { ?>` . The error tell me this: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: Yep, you can also nest if/else statements.

Comment: @focusoft http://3v4l.org/tqQTZ - seems to work for me, perhaps you have accidentally modified the code or you have too many closing `}`. If you wish to post your code to a codepad website, I can attempt to spot the error.

Comment: I see where was my error. Something else I want to ask: I can add HMTL page as content after form submission? I will test anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can focusoft. But use it intelligently, any code that should be displayed in both 'pages' should be left outside of the if/else. There is no point having your design/layout code in both cases of the if/else!